# What type of wire should I use for about 80ft run to a She Shed in 1" conduit for a 60 AMP subpanel. Can I use 6-6-6-6 Gray Stranded AL SER Cable?

Tags: subpanel

I want to run electric to my wife's She Shed. I am thinking a 60 AMP service is what I want. What type of wire should I use for about 80ft in 1" conduit. Can I use 6-6-6-6 Gray Stranded AL SER Cable ?

Comment: Is the 1" conduit already in the ground, or could you drop 1.5" or even 2" in if necessary?

Comment: She Shed, she said, be the seashore.

Comment: If you're using Conduit, don't use Cable. If you're using Cable, don't use Conduit.

Comment: You don’t need a full sized grounding conductor “use” underground service entrance cable underground it will have a down sized ground. Is your conduit already in the ground ?

Comment: Yes the 1" conduit is already in. So should I just #6/3 with ground (basically a #6/4 wire)?

Comment: Do I need 2 grounding rods ?

Comment: something like #6/3 Type NM-B Cable with Ground Wire

Comment: With a 100 AMP Breaker Panel instead of a 60 AMP because 100 AMP are readily available ?

Comment: Could I use this (75ft is long enough from box to box) ? -  75' 6/3 Type NM-B Cable with Ground Wire Model Number: 3691542 Menards® SKU: 3691542

Comment: @RandyCOttaway A 100A breaker panel is fine (just make sure to get enough *spaces* in that panel, and make sure to get the appropriate 60A breaker for your main panel to protect your feeder); HOWEVER, that NM cable is VERY NOT FINE!  (NM is *absolutely* no good in wet locations, as it has a paper separator in it that wicks water into boxes, leading to hard-to-troubleshoot failures down the road.)   Can you not get 6AWG THHN where you're at for some bizarre reason?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am trying to get it from Menards, Home Depot or Lowes. Is there a THHN all together or is the THHN single wire only so I would need to do 3 #6 and one #10 for the ground ?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Should it be solid or is stranded ok ?

Comment: @RandyCOttaway -- the THHN is single wires only, and you'll be getting stranded (solid THHN is not made in sizes larger than #10 as larger solid wires are too stiff to pull through conduit).  Note that THHN in that size may not just be on a store shelf for you to buy -- you may have to order it in (either in store or online) for pickup in a few days.  (It seems my local Lowes' has it available by-the-foot, but your mileage definitely will vary, so look before you leap!)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank You for the info. 1 Last question can I just use the 6/3 Type NB that I already bought if I remove the paper inside 2-4 feet from the ends or if I just take the 4 wires out of the casing the whole way ?

Comment: @RandyCOttaway -- no, neither of those will work -- the wire inside NM is *not labeled* (marked) for individual use

Answer (score 1):

### SER cable is no good underground

NEC 338.12(A) point 2 prohibits the use of type SE (style U or style R, it doesn't matter) cable underground, even when in a conduit/raceway.  Besides, you really don't want to be pulling that alligator of a cable down a 1" conduit to begin with, as it won't *fit* very well at all, leaving you calling the electrician in to bail you out.  In particular, a typical 6-6-6-6 Al SER cable has an OD of 0.717" or 18.2 mm, which means it takes up 260.5 mm<sup>2</sup> of fill area.  This *barely* fits into 1" conduits of most conduit types, a bad omen for a multiconductor cable to begin with, and does *not* fit in the worst-case scenario of a 1", Schedule 80 PVC conduit.

Furthermore, 6AWG Al is limited to 50A when landed on the 75°C capable terminations in distribution equipment, *not* the 60A you were hoping for.  As a result of all of this, I'd put in 3 6AWG *copper* THHN/THWN wires instead (two blacks and one white), with a bare 10AWG copper ground wire.  This takes up a mere 103.4 mm<sup>2</sup> of fill area, less than *half* of the space the cable takes up, while being a *far* easier pull through the conduit, and fully Code-legal in this underground application.

### Once you get to the shed....

Once you reach the shed, you'll need to install a subpanel there.  This is where most folks screw up; they chintz out and put in a tiny panel, thinking that's all their feeder can support or simply looking to shave a few bucks off the project cost, when they're really setting themselves up for an expensive panel swap down the road.  Instead, I'd put in a 24-space or 30-space, 100 or 125A, *main breaker* panel.  The oversized main breaker in the subpanel is no big deal as it's simply serving as the shutoff switch required for the structure by NEC 225.31, and the extra spaces provide plenty of expansion room for whatever crazy tools your significant other decides to get into.

Because you're putting in a feeder and subpanel, you'll also need to run some 8AWG or 6AWG bare copper from that subpanel to a pair of 8' ground rods driven a minimum of 6-8' apart.  This provides natural electricity, such as lightning-induced voltages, a path back to Mother Nature, while the equipment grounding wire in the feeder provides an easy route wayward utility-generated electricity can take to get back to the neutral-ground bond in your main panel and thus back to your utility.  As a result of this, you'll need to make sure the bonding screw or strap in your new subpanel is *removed*, or simply left uninstalled to begin with, when you install it.

### TORQUE ALL LUGS TO SPEC

Last but not least, 2017 NEC 110.14(D) requires that all breaker and loadcenter/panel lug-type connections be torqued to the labeled torque values using an inch-pound torque wrench or torque screwdriver.  Even if your jurisidiction hasn't adopted the 2017 NEC, this is still a good idea anyway, as this Code change was made because of [studies that were done](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/) that showed that the electrician's office manager (or a DIYer) was as equally unlikely to torque a connection correctly with regular hand tools as the electrician was!

Answer (score 0):

SER rating alone is not approved for burial, even in conduit.

#6 AL even if allowed to be terminated at 75° is only good for 50A, you will need minimum 4-4-4-8 AL, which individual XHHW-2 would fit in 1" conduit, but 1.25 would be advised.

Comment: SER is approved for wet locations, just not underground.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You're right , will fix that.